# Loading modules in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have a problem trying to load some modules.

`controller1.js`:

```
angular.module('LPC')
   .controller('lista_peliculas_controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.hola="hola peliculas";
   }]);
```

And `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('mis_peliculas', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/pagina_principal",{
            templateUrl: "views/pagina_principal.html",
            controller: "lista_peliculas_controller"
        })
        .when("/lista_peliculas",{
            templateUrl: "views/lista_peliculas.html",
            controller: "lista_peliculas_controller"
        })
        .when("/lista_series",{
            templateUrl: "views/lista_series.html",
            controller: "lista_series_controller"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/pagina_principal"
        })
});
```

The console says that there is a problem with the injector.
Can you find the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `angular-route.js` .   [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

> The ngRoute module provides routing and deeplinking services and
>   directives for AngularJS apps.

How do you fix it?

```
var app = angular.module('mis_peliculas', ['ngRoute','LPC']);
```

**And**

```
angular.module('LPC', [])
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, it seems that the bug was by ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to use right module name:

```
angular.module('mis_peliculas')
   .controller('lista_peliculas_controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.hola="hola peliculas";
   }]);
```

and if you want to use separate modules, you need to initiliaze it first and inject it into your main module

```
angular.module('LPC',[])
   .controller('lista_peliculas_controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.hola="hola peliculas";
   }]);

var app = angular.module('mis_peliculas', ['LPC']);
```

I assume your routing is already set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

without the complete log of the error i can't be more precise, but i think that the injection error could be related to your module not being instantiated.

try to change

```
angular.module('LPC') //here you get a reference to a module, that could cause your error
```

to

```
angular.module('LPC', []) //here you instantiate a module
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the 'LPC' Module to your app 'mis_peliculas' module for it use the 'lista_peliculas_controller' Controller which is in 'LPC' Module.

Try this code

```
angular.module('LPC',[])
   .controller('lista_peliculas_controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.hola="hola peliculas";
   }]);
```

This should be your controller1.js and should be defined before you define your app. Now the app.js should look like

```
var app = angular.module('mis_peliculas', ['LPC']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/pagina_principal",{
                templateUrl: "views/pagina_principal.html",
                controller: "lista_peliculas_controller"
            })
            .when("/lista_peliculas",{
                templateUrl: "views/lista_peliculas.html",
                controller: "lista_peliculas_controller"
            })
            .when("/lista_series",{
                templateUrl: "views/lista_series.html",
                controller: "lista_series_controller"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/pagina_principal"
            })
    });
```

This should remove all the errors and you should be able to use the controller from other module.

Hope it helps